# Iterating with Each Quiz Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append, each

```js
$('p').each(function (index) {
  var letters = $(this).text().length;
 $('p').appendTo('<span> Here is ' + letters + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A amet vel fugit repellendus, magni blanditiis delectus autem dicta, omnis odit beatae iusto asperiores, iste. Delectus, eaque reiciendis quibusdam cupiditate molestias officia perspiciatis corporis cumque saepe voluptatem, magnam magni asperiores a!</p>
```

Hello There , I will appreciate a lot any help with my code , I need to count all letters per one `<p>` Tags and show it on the end of `<p>` tag but my code count all of `<p>` tags which I have on the page and put it together in every of them , can any body give me advise what is . wrong and how to fix it , Thank you so much

Comment: use this context for this. instead of `$('p')` use `$(this)`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! I'm just start my way in programming so hard to understand what this exactly mean

Answer (score 1):

Because `$('p')` will find every `<p>` in page the same way you are using it to set up the initial query

You want the specific instance inside the `each` which is `$(this)` and you want `append()` not `appendTo()`

```js
$('p').each(function (index) {
  var letters = $(this).text().length;
  $(this).append('<span style="color:red"> Here is ' + letters + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A amet vel fugit repellendus, magni blanditiis delectus autem dicta, omnis odit beatae iusto asperiores, iste. Delectus, eaque reiciendis quibusdam cupiditate molestias officia perspiciatis corporis cumque saepe voluptatem, magnam magni asperiores a!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! I'm just start my way in programming so hard to understand what this exactly mean

Comment: When in doubt...look at examples and details in the api ... http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('p').each(function (index) {
  $('<span></span>',{text :  " Here is " + $(this).text().length + ""}).css({color:'blue'}).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A amet vel fugit repellendus, magni blanditiis delectus autem dicta, omnis odit beatae iusto asperiores, iste. Delectus, eaque reiciendis quibusdam cupiditate molestias officia perspiciatis corporis cumque saepe voluptatem, magnam magni asperiores a!</p>
```